# Enabling/Installing/Downloading Portal for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, installation, arcgis-10.4, download, arcgis-portal

How can I install Portal for ArcGIS?  I have installed ArcGIS for server 10.1 on linux.

I read in ArcNews that [Portal for ArcGIS is available with the ArcGIS 10.1 release](http://www.esri.com/news/arcnews/summer11articles/portal-for-arcgis-new-software-product-for-making-maps-sharing-and-collaborating-in-a-secure-environment.html).

How can I enable it?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the Portal for ArcGIS is not available directly to ArcGIS Server 10.1 users. You are supposed to obtain the software/license via your local Esri distributor. In 10.2, however, the Portal for ArcGIS media is included with ArcGIS Server. This means you are able to install the software on your own (i.e., download via Customer Care portal). The Portal is licensed as a separate extension of Server.

In 10.2, according to the [functionality matrix for 10.2](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf&ei=grauUvLdO6fK4AS39oGgDw&usg=AFQjCNGFIjJtVBkwtzX_tl3aT2PKrtJ7KA&bvm=bv.57967247,d.bGE), you can install Portal extension and license it only with ArcGIS Server Advanced level (which means you cannot use Portal with Basic or Standard level of ArcGIS Server license).

Answer (score 2):

I find in ArcGIS Help:

**10.1**: [not much](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00030000001p000000)

**10.2**: [Portal for ArcGIS Linux Installation Guide](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-portal-linux/10.2/#/Welcome_to_the_Portal_for_ArcGIS_Linux_installation_guide/028z0000000t000000/)

I know you're on 10.1.

But I don't know if this difference in help docs reflects a real difference in functionality, or simply a substantial improvement in documentation. If it's the latter, then maybe the 10.2 help docs will be useful for you.

Maybe someone who has set up a Portal in 10.1 can jump in with more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can download it via https://my.esri.com. But it is only available if you've purchased it.

Comment: There is no trial version for it. Such as ArcGIS Online,or Arcmap

Comment: Indeed, as I said you need to purchase it. Or you might discuss with your local distributor to see if they can provide you with a trial.

Answer (score 1):

For ArcGIS 10.4.1, and presumably some earlier versions, on the [Portal for ArcGIS](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/) page there is a link to:

> [Download at My Esri](https://my.esri.com/#/)